# How to stop replacing relative path to absolute path all files automatically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

My problems is when I was coding the editor of vscode auto replace from relative path to absolute path of all files in my project automatically.

For example:
When I import like this:

```html
import { login } from '../logic.redux/action'
```

Five minutes latter(maybe some actions like save or import another file) it will convert to:

```html
import { login } from '@module/login/logic.redux/action'
```

And seriously it's override all files to absolute files. Tell me what am I doing wrong

My project include : Typescript + react-native(project)

Here is my tsconfig.json

```html
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "module": "es6",
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
  "sourceMap": true,
  "allowJs": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "jsx": "react-native",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "noEmit": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noImplicitThis": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": false,
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
   "@conf/*": ["./conf/*"],
   "@i18n/*": ["./i18n/*"],
   "@module/*": ["./module/*"],
   "@router/*": ["./router/*"],
   "@theme/*": ["./theme/*"],
   "@tpl/*": ["./tpl/*"],
   "@util/*": ["./util/*"]
  }
  
 },
 "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And here is my tslint.json

```html
{
 "defaultSeverity": "error",
 "extends": [
  "tslint-config-airbnb"
 ],
 "jsRules": {},
 "rules": {
  "indent": [
   true,
   "tabs", 4
  ],
  "ter-indent": [
   false
  ],
  "semicolon": [
   true,
   "never"
  ],
  "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
  "quotemark": [
   true,
   "single",
   "jsx-double"
  ],
  "ordered-imports": true,
  "interface-name": [
   false
  ],
  "max-line-length": [
   true,
   140
  ],
  "no-console": [
   false
  ],
  "no-empty-interface": false,
  "no-var-requires": false,
  "import-name": false,
  "no-consecutive-blank-lines": [
   true,
   0
  ],
  "no-increment-decrement": false,
  "variable-name": [
   true,
   "ban-keywords",
   "check-format",
   "allow-pascal-case"
  ],
  "no-unused-variable": false
 },
 "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

And user setting in vscode

```html
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Bimbo Theme",
    "sublimeTextKeymap.promptV3Features": true,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary",
    "editor.rulers": [100],
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "solid",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "todohighlight.isEnable": true,
    "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
    "gitlens.advanced.messages": {
        "suppressShowKeyBindingsNotice": true
    },
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave":true,
    "tslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
    "tslint.configFile": "./tslint.ide.json",
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
 "editor.tabSize": 4,

}
```

And here is List extension of

```html
PeterJausovec.vscode-docker
abotteram.typescript-react-snippets
ajhyndman.jslint
anseki.vscode-color
azemoh.one-monokai
bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles
chenxsan.vscode-standardjs
chong.vscode-typescript-react-redux-snippets
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
cmstead.jsrefactor
Compulim.compulim-vscode-closetag
cssho.vscode-svgviewer
Dart-Code.dart-code
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
DotJoshJohnson.xml
dracula-theme.theme-dracula
dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets
eamodio.gitlens
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
eg2.tslint
emmanuelbeziat.vscode-great-icons
esbenp.prettier-vscode
formulahendry.auto-close-tag
formulahendry.auto-complete-tag
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
HookyQR.beautify
infeng.vscode-react-typescript
jundat95.react-native-snippet
karyfoundation.comment
kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks
mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel
miclo.sort-typescript-imports
mohsen1.prettify-json
monokai.theme-monokai-pro-vscode
ms-python.python
ms-vscode.node-debug2
ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings
naumovs.color-highlight
patrys.vscode-code-outline
pawelgrzybek.bimbo-theme
pmneo.tsimporter
pnp.polacode
richie5um2.vscode-sort-json
santosh.react-native-snippet
shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced
stevencl.addDocComments
teabyii.ayu
vsmobile.vscode-react-native
waderyan.gitblame
wayou.vscode-todo-highlight
wix.vscode-import-cost
xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets
yzhang.markdown-all-in-one
zengxingxin.sort-js-object-keys
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open vscode user settings: `File -> Preferences -> Settings`

set `"javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "prompt",`

`prompt` on each rename
`always` update paths automatically
`never` rename paths and don't prompt me

yours are probably set on `always`

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall vscode.
And select 'no and never' button when you change name file it will show the pop up look like this "Automatically update imports for moved file"

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53832